# jquery change & by? on the first parameter

Tags: jquery

I have a problem on an infinite scroll when I scroll my first parameter in the url is & page when it should be? Page. I would like to add a check of this url and if the first parameter starts with & I would like to replace it with?.
Here is what it is returning to me currently:

```
http://v3.test/1031-baskets&page=2?uri=1604995770873
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Where is this URL coming from? The code producing it is what's broken (assuming `page` is meant to be a query string parameter). *That's* what you should look to fix, rather than changing the URL after the fact.

Comment: While I agree with the above, here's a one-liner: `"http://v3.test/1031-baskets&page=2?uri=1604995770873".split(/[?&]/).join("&").replace(/&/, "?")`  note it's replace `/&/` not `/&/g` for just the first one

Comment: @freedomn-m - Heh, I thought about `split` but went the other way. Not sure `split` isn't better though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `http://v3.test/1031-baskets&page=2?uri=1604995770873` has no `page` parameter; the `&` is **part of the pathname** in the URL. It breaks down like this:

- Protocol: `http:`
- Host: `v3.test`
- Pathname: `/1031-baskets&page=2`
- Search (query string): `?uri=1604995770873`

If you change the first `&` to a `?` and the other `?` to an `&`, you change the meaning of the URL.

If that's what you want to do, it's a straight-forward pair of `replace` calls, but you **only** want to do it if the `&` appears prior to the `?`:

```
const indexOfAmp = url.indexOf("&");
const indexOfQ = url.indexOf("?");
if (indexOfAmp !== -1 && indexOfAmp < indexOfQ) {
    url = url.replace("?", "&").replace("&", "?");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let url = "http://v3.test/1031-baskets&page=2?uri=1604995770873";
console.log("Before:", url);
const indexOfAmp = url.indexOf("&");
const indexOfQ = url.indexOf("?");
if (indexOfAmp !== -1 && indexOfAmp < indexOfQ) {
    url = url.replace("?", "&").replace("&", "?");
}
console.log("After: ", url);
```